# Render form in template

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have made the following .tpl.php template:

```
<?php print drupal_render($element["term"]); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($element["search"]);?>
<?php print drupal_render($element["advanced_search"]);?>
<?php print drupal_render_children($element);?>
```

But the form tag is not generated, so the form cannot be submitted ... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are not able to get search form or any other thing ?

Comment: I see the fields but when click the search button it does not submits, because the form tag is not rendered

Comment: How does your hook_theme() function look like?

Comment: I think we need to see the $elements that you are attempting to render to build the form.

Answer (score 6):

You can add search box in a preprocess function in your template.php:

```
<?php
/*
 *  Preprocess page.tpl.php to inject the $search_box variable back into D7.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $search_box = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_form'));
  $variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
}
```

Then you just need to print the variable in your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $search_box; ?>
```

Comment: If i use drupal_render i get "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting" , if i use drupal_render_children i see the form but there is not <form> tag in html so it does not work

Comment: Why do you render that form in preprocess?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can add search box in a preprocess function in template.php of
   your theme:

   ```
   function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables){
         $search_box = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_form'));
         $variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
       }
   ```
2. Then you just need to print the variable in your page.tpl.php:

   ```
   <?php print $search_box; ?>
   ```

You could also use module_invoke, but you shouldn't have php logic in template files:

```
  $block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search');
  print render($block);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wish I had a better explanation, but if you're using a custom theme hook, make sure it doesn't match your form id. For example, if your form is "mymodule_my_form," don't name your theme hook "mymodule_my_form." I've run into issues rendering a form in a template because of this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to render complete form with individual fields.

Just change the last line of your template file with this one -

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($element['form']);?>
```

Comment: ? I think your anwer is missing a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Find form_id of the form you want to display.
( you may use [Get Form ID](https://www.drupal.org/project/get_form_id) module )

Then you can put any form in any place, example:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('YOUR_FORM_ID');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue, realized was printing `drupal_render($form)` in a fake html  tag(some design time html left-over) hence no real form - removed it and there stood the real form staring at me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution now;

```
$form = drupal_get_form('custom_example_form', $adverts);
  print '<form id="'.$form['#id'].'" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="'.$form['#method'].'" action="'.$form['#action'].'">'; 
  print render($form['name']);
  print render($form['descriere']);
  print render($form['submit']);
  print render($form['form_id']);
  print render($form['form_build_id']);
  print '</form>';
```

See this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/111833/23593

Answer (score 0):

```
$wnid = 5; //form id
$wnode = node_load($wnid); load the node id
$form = drupal_get_form('webform_client_form_' . $wnid, $wnode, array());
print render($form);
```

This will give you your webform.

Answer (score 0):

My form was in an include file, mymodule/includes/mymodule.example_form.inc, doing the following worked for me:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_main_page(&$variables) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'includes/mymodule.example_form');
    $example_form = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('mymodule_example_form'));
    $variables['example_form'] = $example_form;
}
```

Then in template file, `<?php print $example_form; ?>`