# Drupal render form not rendering a form

Tags: forms, theming

I have a cutom module which creates a page with a custom form.
the problem is that i don't print whole form at once like :

```
$form = drupal_get_form('custom_example_form', $adverts);
print render($form);
```

Rather my code is like:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('custom_example_form', $adverts);
print render($form['name']);
print render($form['descriere']);
print render($form['submit']);
print render($form['form_id']);
print render($form['form_build_id']);
```

The problem us that is second example drupal is not generating

```
<form id="" accept-charset="" method="" action="">
```

How do i generate  in second situation?

Comment: You should not mix print statements (for HTML markup) and drupal_get_form() in the same file. Print statements (for HTML markup) belongs to template files. A template should not call drupal_get_form() (because getting a form is not the job of a template).

Comment: you're right, now i realized my mistake but is too late to get back, I ended using an alternative, non-elegant solution however.

Answer (score 2):

You should not print individual children elements of the form array, but render it completely (with `render($form)`).

If you want to fine tune the markup inside the `<form>` tag, you need to alter the form (using [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)) or provide a custom theme used for the form (i.e. in [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) returns an items with the form ID as key).

Answer (score 1):

If you are selectively rendering the form, you could unset some fields and render the whole form.

Comment: this could be a solution at least is works

Comment: Rather than unsetting some array indexes, it is better to change the `#access` property for those form fields that needs to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I ended using this method to solve my issue, not an elegant solutions but it works:

in tpl:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('custom_example_form', $adverts);
print '<form id="'.$form['#id'].'" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="'.$form['#method'].'" action="'.$form['#action'].'">'; 
print render($form['name']);
print render($form['descriere']);
print render($form['submit']);
print render($form['form_id']);
print render($form['form_build_id']);
print '</form>';
```

it doesn't look good but is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$form = drupal_get_form('custom_example_form');
print render($form);
```