# Form in template without <form> tags

Tags: forms, theming

My forms dont seem to have  tags wrapping them in my templates.
What am I doing wrong here?

I have a template whith some calls to theme() inside it.
Two of these are forms with their own template.
This template is called from a block_view().

my modules block function:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('stappenoverzicht_appointment_form');
  $reset = drupal_get_form('stappenoverzicht_reset_form');

  $block['content'] = theme('overzicht', array('status' => $status, 'links' =>$links, 'form' => $form, 'reset' => $reset));
```

my modules theme function:

```
$return['overzicht'] = array(
'variables' => array('status' => array(), 'links' => array(), 'form' => null, 
 'reset'      => null),
'template' => 'templates/dashboard--stappen-overzicht',
    'render element' => 'form',
```

);

```
$return['appointment'] = array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'templates/form--appointment',
    );
$return['reset'] = array(
    'arguments' => array('form' => null),
    'render element' => 'form',
    'template' => 'templates/form--reset',
);
return $return;
```

base tpl:

```
<div class="appointment-container">
   <?php print theme('appointment', array('form' => $form));?>
</div>
<div class="reset-button-container">
   <?php print theme('reset', array('form' => $reset));?>
</div>
```

form--reset:

```
<div class="reset-submit-btn">
       <?php print drupal_render($form['submit']);?>
</div>
  <i><?php print drupal_render($form['description']);?></i>
<?php
print drupal_render_children($form);
?>
```

I came across this [Render form in template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48247/render-form-in-template) answere here, but I want to manipulate the wrapping html as shown in the reset template.

Comment: If you don't pass the form array through `drupal_get_form` or relevant function that builds the form array (by adding CSRF tokens, etc), you won't see any form tags which I believe is the case here.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this is all called from within a block_view(). Also if I just add print render($form) in the tempklate it works as normal. I have editted my question.

Answer (score 1):

your module should be like this:

```
function yourmodule_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['path/to/form'] = array(
        'title' => 'Page Title',
        'description' => 'Page Description',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('yourmodule_form_function'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
}

function yourmodule_form_function()
{
   //build form api here as array
   //return array
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: However if this is going through the theme engine it may be slightly different though the principle is the same

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, this is indeed how I would normally do this. However my code is called within a hook_block_view. The block is then put inside a panel.

Comment: look here:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15152/form-within-a-block
it uses drupal_render(drupal_get_form('yourmodule_form_function'))

Answer (score 0):

Just create a form

```
<?php
    function testform(&$form,$form_state){
    $form['description'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Description'),
        '#default_value' => '',

      );
    return $form;

    }
    ?>
```

Now in menu you can use theme function

```
<?php
theme('test',array('myform'=>render(drupal_get_form('testform'))));
?>
```

And in your template file form can be used this way

```
<?php
print $myform;
?>
```

Hope it will work for you.