# Trying to to display form in template

Tags: 7, theming, ubercart

I'm trying to display a form in a template (not my first choice, but I'm restricted in what I can do here) and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do it.

I'm trying to tie into the Ubercart Addresses module to allow the user to select from one of the countries available to them.

I believe this information is located in `uc_addresses_get_address_form`

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
<?php  print render(drupal_get_form('uc_addresses_get_address_form'))?>
```

But this doesn't seem to add the form information I want.

How do I get this information into a template file?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
drupal_render(drupal_get_form('uc_addresses_get_address_form'))
```

Check [Render form in template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48247/render-form-in-template)

Comment: Isn't render() just a wrapper for drupal_render()?

Comment: And no, putting this in my template.php did not work.

Comment: What is it giving you? Have you included the file with the form?